# See historical packet receipt statistics in Windows

Tags: wireshark, packet, statistics

I know this is a long shot, but it would be really useful to me right now.

Does anyone know of a Windows function or 3rd party tool that can show stats about the receipt of packets on a network adapter historically (over the course of the few days, ideally)?

The scenario is that a computer has a dedicated network card dedicate to receiving a single packet stream (managed by a filtered switch), that appears to have not received any packets for a random block of 10 minutes several days ago. Since this is not reproducable or common, it would be nice to be able to determine if this is actually the case (as opposed to the software failing to handle the received packets) by viewing some historical data that would demonstrate a drop in the number of packets received within those ten minutes, rather than having to run wireshark for the foreseeable future in case it happens again.

Again, long shot, but thought I'd ask the question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default automatic packet logging within the Windows OS (that I am aware of). If you are trying to get statistics on an event that has already happened, you are probably out of luck.

My best suggestion would be to scour the Event Viewer during the 10 minutes or so you are concerned about.

Going forward however, there are many good packet capture programs. The one which you have mentioned is what I would use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know the network adapter status window keeps a count of packets, but that only goes back to the last lease renew anyway. So I guessed I was probably grasping at straws. Thanks anyway!